# Вызов функции по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript

В эфире снова мои бестолковые вопросы, но все мы учимся, так что, пожалуйста, не вздыхайте и не делайте фейспалмы.

В общем, проблема такова, что при клике на кнопку, должно возвращатся значение, индекс той кнопки, на которую кликнули. А у меня возвращается все. Пожалуйста, хелп ми.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function map(list, func) {
  var f = func || function(list) {};

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    (f(list[i], i));
  }
}

function show(item, index) {
  console.log(item + index + 'clicked');
}

map(list, show);
```

```html
<button onclick='map(list, show)'>Один</button>
<button onclick='map(list,show)'>Два</button>
```

Comment: console.log(item + index + 'clicked');
Все правильно вроде бы выводится: элемент (объект приведенный к стрингу) + индекс + 'clicked'

Comment: если, например, оставить просто 'clicked', то текст будет выводиться два раза за 1 клик по 1 кнопке. а мне нужно, чтобы один

Comment: так вам нужно вывести только индекс нажатой кнопки?

Comment: у вас 2 лога так, как у вас в цикле ф-я `show` вызывается дважды

Comment: да, именно) но чтобы это делала функция map

Comment: @IngridBelan, опишите конкретно что Вам нужно, и обновите вопрос , иначе выяснение Ваших требований может затянутся

Comment: скорее всего надо бы немного переделать логику. во-первых убрать inline js из html (дело вкуса, но...не совсем). и во-вторых - навесить обработчики клика в коде... примерно так https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802111/6104996  ... где, как-раз, и определится индекс элемента

Comment: у вас просто функция запускала цикл и применяла функцию show ко всем элементам в листе. Проверки не хватало на кликнутую кнопку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так?

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
function showThis(target){
    var index;
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        if(list[i] == target) index = i;
    }
    console.log(target + index + 'clicked');
}
```

```html
<button onclick='showThis(this)'>Один</button>
<button onclick='showThis(this)'>Два</button>
```

Comment: почему Вы все так любите вешать обработчики в ХТМЛ?

Comment: хз) в вопросе так.

Comment: спасибо огромное! и вообще спасибо всем-всем за помощь, вы чудесные)

Answer (score 7):

```js
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'),function(element,index){
  element.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log('button index ' + index)
  },false)
})
```

```html
<button>Один</button>
<button>Два</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));

function showIndex(item) {
    console.log(nodes.indexOf(item));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showIndex(this)">Один</button>
<button onclick="showIndex(this)">Два</button>
<button onclick="showIndex(this)">Три</button>
```